# Additional Display

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, 20.04, amd-graphics

After installation Ubuntu I had a problem with NVIDIA graphics drivers. After many battles finally I made it !!! I have the newest driver from NVIDIA. The problem is:

**That I can't change any graphics option: resolution, graduation, display graphics on additional devices. This is the main problem for me. Because I must use additional monitor but after connecting by HDMI there is no reaction.**

I think that a problem is with my computer. I have two graphics processors. One from the graphic card (NVIDIA) second one from the main processor (AMD). I had the same problem on Windows and the solution was installing additional drivers for AMD. But on Ubuntu, I can't find that kind for drivers. There are just for windows.
Please help.

My computer details:

ASUS TUF GAMING, AMD RYZOR 5 4600 H, GEFORCE 1650TI

After lspci:

[image]

After `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`:
information: there is no file or catalog on this name.

When I install xorg - it's impossible to start Ubuntu -just black screen.
To start system I must use this solution:

```
delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf
make sure nvidia-prime is installed (sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime)
switch to nvidia (sudo prime-select nvidia)
remove stray blacklist files (sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf)
update the initrd (sudo update-initramfs -u)
reboot
```

Comment: which Ubuntu version?

Comment: 20.04 LTS  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Answer (score 0):

OMG ! That was so easy that I can't believe.

**THAT IS SOLUTION:**

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

add into line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFEULT`  into double quotes: `amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1.`

Save it. Confirm by:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And it's done.